# How to use auth token generated on Dropbox App Console with dropbox-api (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropbox-api

I'm trying to use dropbox with generated access token from Dropbox App Console.

If I execute:

```
curl https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info -H "Authorization:Bearer <MY-ACCESS-TOKEN>"
```

request successfully returns my account info.

How can I use this access_token with 'dropbox-api'?

I tried (in Rails console):

```
Dropbox::API::Config.app_key = 'my_app_key'
Dropbox::API::Config.app_secret = 'my_app_secret'
Dropbox::API::Config.mode = 'dropbox'
client = Dropbox::API::Client.new(token: 'my_generated_access_token')
client.account
```

...and get: "Dropbox::API::Error::Unauthorized: 401 - Bad or expired token"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like that gem (assuming I found the right one: https://github.com/futuresimple/dropbox-api/) doesn't support OAuth 2, so there's no way to use the token you generated via the App Console. You'll need to auth via OAuth 1 if you want to use that gem.